Тире в предложении отец - хирург, и как правильно "отец был хирург" или хирургом?

Мои родители тоже были врачами: отец – хирург, мама – врач-окулист.

Или правильно было бы:

Мои родители тоже были врачами: отец – хирургом, мама –
врачом-окулистом.


Правильно:
Мои родители тоже были врачами: отец – хирург, мама – врач-окулист.
Творительный падеж может использоваться при наличии связки, а при отсутствии связки только именительный падеж (кроме разговорной речи).
Розенталь §179. Формы сказуемого
 Существительное и прилагательное в функции именной части 
 составного сказуемого могут стоять как в форме 
 именительного, так и в форме творительного падежа; ср.: И в 
 семье его Савельич был свой человек (Мельников: Печерский). 
 – И у Ивашиных он был своим человеком (Чехов); 

 1) обычно в этих случаях именительный падеж 
 существительного указывает на устойчивый признак предмета, 
 на постоянно присущую ему качественную характеристику, а 
 творительный падеж – на временный признак. 

 2) при отсутствии связки употребляется форма именительного 
 падежа, например: Мой отец врач. Постановка именного 
 сказуемого в форме творительного падежа встречается в 
 разговорной речи, например: У меня мать здесь учительницей 
 (Федин); 

